# adding new validation method using HookEventDispatcherInterface::FORM_ALTER event

Tags: 8, hooks, event-subscribers

I'm trying to add a new validation method for 'user_login_form' using [HookEventDispatcher](https://www.drupal.org/project/hook_event_dispatcher/releases/8.x-1.27) module and events:

```
class MyFormEventsSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface {


public static function getSubscribedEvents() {
      return [ HookEventDispatcherInterface::FORM_ALTER => 'alterForm'];
  }


public function alterForm(FormAlterEvent $event) {

    if ($event->getFormId() == 'user_login_form') {

      $form = &$event->getForm();
      $form['#validate'][] = 'my_api_authentication';

    }
  }

  function my_api_authentication(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $test = 1;
  }
}
```

But i never reach *my_api_authentication* function. How i need to refer it and where should be suposed to be implemented ?

May be i should manage with *hook_form_FORM_ID_alter* instead *FORM_ALTER HookEventDispatcherInterface* event ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it that way too:
in Oriented object way don't call the method like `'my_api_authentication'` it should be `[$this, 'myApiAuthentication']` and also the method should be Camel Cases, try with the following:

```
class MyFormEventsSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface {

  public static function getSubscribedEvents() {
    return [HookEventDispatcherInterface::FORM_ALTER => 'alterForm'];
  }

  public function alterForm(FormAlterEvent $event) {
    if ($event->getFormId() == 'user_login_form') {
      $form = &$event->getForm();
      $form['#validate'][] = [$this, 'myApiAuthentication'];
    }
  }
  function myApiAuthentication(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    // Your code validation here.
  }

}
```

Comment: works like a charm!. Thanks @berramou. I'm new in PHP world, where can i learn this syntaxis? :  [$this, 'string'] . It's new for me :-)